# Connecting PCI, ArcGIS, and XTools with Python?

Tags: arcpy, installation, geomatica, xtools-pro

I have a process that I'm trying to fully automate. There are 3 broadly defined chunks. An intial ArcGIS chunk that uses XTools. A PCI chunk. and a plain ArcGIS chunk. PCI python requires 64bit arcpy in order to connect. Is there any way to do this and still use XTools, which I understand, require 32bit arcpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use both X-tools and PCI in the same .py file. However you can create a .bat file to run the 32-bit version of python.exe with the x-tools using .py and then run the pci .py with the 64-bit python.exe.

Keep in mind that if you are running arcpy through cmd.exe that you can't, (or I haven't found a way to), use arcpy.getparameter etc, so things have to be hard coded or obtained via os.walk and fnmatch.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what NorthLand said, you could have your main tool in a .py to call with ArcGIS (32 bit), then use either Popen or os.system to call the secondary script. If you need it in a batch, use sys.argv (which is like getparameterastext.)